# How to use Meziantou WASM infinite scroll with List<T> and pagination?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement your Blazor infinite scroll component with my response from API which returns PaginationResponse.

```
public class PagingResponse<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
} 

public class MetaData
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public bool HasPrevious => CurrentPage > 1;
    public bool HasNext => CurrentPage < TotalPages;
}
```

I have tested provided example and it works great

```
    <InfiniteScrolling ItemsProvider="GetItems">
        <ItemTemplate Context="item">
            <p>Item @item</p>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LoadingTemplate>
            <div>Loading...</div>
        </LoadingTemplate>
    </InfiniteScrolling>

@code {
    async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetItems(InfiniteScrollingItemsProviderRequest request)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate async loading
        return Enumerable.Range(request.StartIndex, 50);
    }
}
```

However, I'm having difficulties combining it with my response type which should act like pagination. Can you provide some assistance?

Comment: "I'm having difficulties" is so vague - you should ask a specific question with details of what you have tried and any errors you see and you should provide a minimal reproduction of the problem where possible. Otherwise this looks like it should be filed as an issue on the author's repo.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to identify when the user scrolled to a new page in order to fetch new page data from API.